# Is it possible to start activity through adb shell?

Tags: android

I want to start activity through adb shell. So that I can launch a specific activity that is needed

Comment: http://charlesliublog.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/how-to-start-an-activity-by-adb-shell-command/

Answer (score 290, accepted):

Launch adb shell and enter the command as follows

```
am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

Comment: You can find out the activity names by running `aapt dump xmltree <APK> AndroidManifest.xml` and looking through the output.

Comment: You can find the apk on the phone with `adb shell pm list packages -f` and retrieve it with `adb pull /path/to/file.apk C:\some\folder` to use with the `aapt` command Chris commented. (aapt is in build-tools)

Comment: Also don't forget add `android:exported="true"` line for an activity in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: A simpler way to find the apk on the phone would be `adb shell pm path <package>`

Comment: @ChristopherGalpin No need to pull the APKs, `adb shell dumpsys package` does the job.

Comment: **aapt** doesn't exist on my samsung tablet... also, there may be an md5 hash prepended to the activity name.

Comment: What does '-n' stands for here? I do not see any documentation on page: https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb under 'Call activity manager (am)' section.

Comment: Neetesh - it's here https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#IntentSpec (click show all)

Comment: @RobinChander Your command only worked as follows `am start -n yourpackagename/activityname`, i.e. the omission of `.`

Answer (score 71):

eg：

MyPackageName is com.example.demo

MyActivityName is com.example.test.MainActivity

```
adb shell am start -n com.example.demo/com.example.test.MainActivity
```

Comment: ^^^ This is correct explanation rather than "
am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname " youre launch activity may be in different package, than in app pakagename

Comment: It works for me only if I add quotes:
adb shell am start -n "com.example.demo/com.example.test.MainActivity"

Comment: Permission Denial: starting Intent ... not exported from uid xxxx

Answer (score 27):

You can also find the name of the current on screen activity using

```
adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep 'mCurrentFocus'
```

Comment: thanks a lot too, I had different build types, and strangely within the activity name, the suffix for the package isn't used :/ did learn something!

Comment: Wow, really surprised. I can see every activity name of every app and every game even they have obfuscation!

Comment: The command doesn't seem to work anymore, at least on my emulator (grep returns nothing) :(

Comment: Try `adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep 'mActivityRecord'`

Comment: Maybe true before 2020, but now on june 2022 this does not show me anything on my Android TV

Answer (score 27):

I run it like AndroidStudio does:

```
am start -n "com.example.app.dev/com.example.app.phonebook.PhoneBookActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
```

**If you have product flavour** like `dev`, it should occur only in application package name but shouldn't occur in activity package name.

For emulator, it works without `android:exported="true"` flag on activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`  but I found it useful to add it for unrooted physical device to make it work.

Answer (score 13):

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.xxx
```

Mention xxx as the action that you mentioned in the manifest file.

Answer (score 11):

For example this will start XBMC:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n org.xbmc.xbmc/android.app.NativeActivity
```

(More general answers are already posted, but I missed a nice example here.)