# SL4A - how can I edit script on PC

Tags: android, scripting, sl4a

Android tutorial explains how can I edit SL4A scripts in the phone.
How can I create and run scripts on the phone from the host PC.
I know `adb forward` command can help but I dont know how can I use it for this purpose.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this post in google groups:
[RemoteControl](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/RemoteControl)

Answer (score 0):

I develop SL4A scripts by running an SSH server on the Android, and then using SFTP to copy files over to the Phone.

From there I launch using a home screen shortcut, but you could also look at the answers to this question for tips: [Launch SL4A Application via adb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636587/launch-sl4a-application-via-adb-shell)