# AndroidStudio - Deploy Application every time

Tags: android, android-studio

On Eclipse, when I try to deploy my application but no changes have been made to the source code I get

```
[2013-05-16 15:12:25 - HomeActivity] Starting activity com.example.android.SplashActivity on device 9009090934434
[2013-05-16 15:12:25 - HomeActivity] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.example.android/.SplashActivity }
[2013-05-16 15:12:25 - HomeActivity] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
```

Is there a way to get the same behaviour on `AndroidStudio` (I ve started using it today - sorry the newbee question). It deploys everytime the application (Or at least seems it to me ). Thanks in advance

Comment: Launch the activity of interest from the device?

Comment: well actually it could be a solution, but I really liked the eclipse behaviour on this matter and I was wandering if I could get it...

Comment: Don't forget that AndroidStudio is an early version at that time (verion 0.1). You may not expect much from an alpha release...

Comment: @Orabîg you are right. I starting using today, I am asking if Someone know if it is possible (maye with some settings).

Comment: better use eclipse while working on live project, otherwise google strictly wrote in "caution" about bugs and mistakes. You will be in trouble in future if it happens.

Comment: that's a bit sad. I was starting to like it

Comment: Workaround? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380590/is-it-possible-to-start-activity-through-adb-shell

Comment: tbh: I am happy that it is finally different :D

Comment: @WarrenFaith I agree, with but something from eclipse was really really helpful and comfortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is because IntelliJ does this command when installing your APK:

```
 DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.blundell.testandroidstudio"
```

the -r is what tell's adb to do a reinstall.

So what I'm saying is it looks like you are tough out of luck :-)

Always remember you can check the run console to see what IntelliJ is doing at run time:

> Waiting for device. Target device: emulator-5554 (ASideJellyBean)
>   Uploading file    local path:
>   /Users/Blundell/AndroidStudioProjects/TestAndroidStudio/TestAndroidStudio/build/apk/TestAndroidStudio-debug-unaligned.apk
>     remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.blundell.testandroidstudio
>   Installing com.blundell.testandroidstudio DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm
>   install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.blundell.testandroidstudio" pkg:
>   /data/local/tmp/com.blundell.testandroidstudio Success
>
> Launching application:
>   com.blundell.testandroidstudio/com.blundell.testandroidstudio.MainActivity.
>   DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: am start -n
>   "com.blundell.testandroidstudio/com.blundell.testandroidstudio.MainActivity"
>   Starting: Intent { cmp=com.blundell.testandroidstudio/.MainActivity }

Comment: Actually I noticed that too. Is there any chance to change the install command?

Comment: that`s sad. Maybe in a while.