# Launch App via adb without knowing Activity name

Tags: android, android-intent, adb

From the post [Is it possible to start activity through adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13380590/is-it-possible-to-start-activity-through-adb-shell), we can start an Android app via adb by

```
adb shell am start -n yourpackagename/.activityname
```

But is it possible to start an Android app via adb without knowing the Activity name? For example, by sending the **android.intent.action.MAIN** intent to a package? Maybe some command like this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n packageName
```

Thanks!!

-Cosmo

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools/25398877#25398877

Comment: rule of thumb - when your accepted answer is nothing but a reference to another post - your question is a duplicate

Comment: @AlexP. But this question is not quite the same—— At least, Google "adb start app" result in lots of `adb shell am start -n packagename/.activityname` things; while Google "adb start app **without knowing Activity name**" won't filter out the duplicated SO question. So this question could be reasonably valuable.

Comment: The duplicated question accidentally has an answer which solves this question. But it's not the duplicated question specifically asked for. This question is asking for a more particular situation.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to launch an app via adb shell making use of the monkey tool.

Using the command from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567904/how-to-start-an-application-using-android-adb-tools/25398877#25398877):

```
adb shell monkey -p app.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1
```

This command simulates the app icon click, so the intent implicit intent LAUNCHER is delivered to the specific receiver declared in app manifest (MAIN)

Comment: It worked. But how to detect Main Activity name? I want to send parameter to a activity (main activity in com.sec.android.gallery3d package), So I should know main activity name.

Comment: Is it also possible, given the APK file, to run this ? Suppose I have an APK file, and I want to be able to install&run it, is it possible?

Comment: I get an error: **No activities found to run, monkey aborted**

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, are you sure the package name is correct? If you're the developer of the application, make sure you have at least one activity with the intent filter with action `android.intent.action.MAIN` and category `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER`

Comment: @androiddeveloper yes, it's possible. Android Studio itself use the adb to install and run the app when you click to run the file. Take a look at [the official adb documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#move) for further details

Comment: @Leuofiridia The question was for a given APK file. I think the IDE already knows the package name and default activity...

Comment: @androiddeveloper you can extract the AndroidManifest.xml file from the apk, and run a binary to text conversion in it to see the package field value. Take a look at [this online tool](http://tools.ankurbhargava.com/APK_Manifest_Converter). Also, if you have the google play link of determined APK, you can see the package name in the URL

Comment: @Leuofiridia Again, it's not a part of adb or anything similar.

Comment: @androiddeveloper after a quick research, I've found that aapt have the means to extract the package name from apk file using this command

`<yourAndroidSdkLocation>/build-tools/<someVersion> /aapt dump permissions <apkFile> | grep package:\  
`

Comment: @Leuofiridia So, suppose I have an APK file on "c:/myGreatApk.apk" , what would be the command/s to install&run it?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I'm not skilled in windows command line nor power shell, but you need to do a port of [this unix script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17289998/1648969) into windows cmd/ps language.

Answer (score 17):

Using latest versions (at least API 25) you can start the default Activity, without knowing its name, and not using `monkey`:

```
PKG=com.android.calculator2
adb shell am start $PKG/$(adb shell cmd package resolve-activity -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER $PKG | sed -n '/name=/s/^.*name=//p')
```

Comment: I don't like nitpicking much but it is not *starting the default Activity, without knowing its name* - it's just *finding the default Activity first, then using it*. Also there is no need to run `cmd package` in a separate `adb shell` session - it could be run in the same shell as `am start`. As a bonus the command will be more OS agnostic (currently it requires some unix shell to process the substitution). Finally, `cmd package resolve-activity` command has a `--brief` parameter which would print the full name of the default activity (as the last line) even without specifying the category.

Comment: `adb shell 'am start $(cmd package resolve-activity --brief com.google.android.calculator | tail -n 1)'` - for Windows replace `'` with `"`

Answer (score 0):

If you have the apk file, you can install and start the app using [droidbot](https://github.com/honeynet/droidbot).

```
> droidbot -d emulator-5554 -a <xxx.apk> -install_app -policy none -count 0
```

DroidBot is based on adb, but it uses static analysis to extract the Activity name automatically.