# How to start a activity which name is unknown?

Tags: android, adb

i wanted to use monkey,but it did not work!

```
startAppCommand = 'moneky -p com.example.packageName -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1'
result = device.shell(startAppCommand)
print('the result of '+startAppCommand + ' is ' + result)
```

then the reslut was :

```
the result of moneky -p com.example.packageName -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 is /system/bin/sh: moneky: not found
```

is there a solution for dealing with the problem?
thanks!

Comment: FYI: `monkey` != `monkeyrunner`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> startAppCommand = 'moneky -p com.example.packageName...

I think it spells `monkey`, not `moneky` which is clearly what error message points to anyway:

> moneky: not found

Comment: @Marcin Orlowski Nice Catch.

Comment: For a solution without using `monkey` see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29931318/launch-app-via-adb-without-knowing-activity-name/41174402#41174402